# Doubts about Pasco photoelectric apparatus

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, photoelectric-effect

I've doing an experiment with [Pasco photoelectric](https://cdn.pasco.com/product_document/Photoelectric-Effect-Apparatus-Manual.pdf), but when plotting the intensity-voltage curve I got that the 436nm line is over 405nm. [image]

But that's normal because the intensity of the 436nm line is like 1.5 bigger than the 405nm one. So if I do an spectroscopy and divide each data by the intensity of the line I got the following plot:

[image]

Which is in accordance with the fact that the intensity (current) measured is inversely proportional to the wavelength. I believe that $I \propto v \propto 1/\sqrt\lambda$ but it is not the case... So I suppose that the current measurement is made another way inside pasco apparatus. Do you have any ideas?

By the way, I have 2 more doubts, around 6V all the lines go near horizontal for a small range of voltage, it may be caused by a gap in the metal?

Finally, I do not really know why the current get saturated when the voltage raises. Is it because all free electrons in the metal are being expelled yet?

Comment: Pasco has a dedicated support center. Why don't you ask them about your results?

Comment: I think you should study the experiment in higher detail; many of your questions have standard answers. I agree with you that your results do suggest something amusing at 6V, but you need to take a whole lot more data before you can make an assertion that you have even detected something. You should first check if your assumptions are correct before checking with your lab manager, who should be the one contacting Pasco if needed. Their expensive equipment do work well.